# Is it possible to make a schedule that Postman executes request?

Tags: postman, schedule

I am using Postman to run a Runner on some specific requests. Is it possible to create a schedule to execute (meaning every day on specific hour)?

Comment: You're on windows or unix? System level scheduler (cron) might do the trick.
Where do you keep the test code? Github?

Answer (score 10):

You can set up a Postman Monitor on your collection, and schedule it to execute the request each minute/hour/weekly basis.

[This](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/monitors/setting_up_monitor/) article can get you started on creating your monitor. Postman allows 1000 monitoring requests for free per month.

PS: Postman gives you details about the responses as in No. of successful requests, response codes, response size etc. I wanted the actual response for my test. So I just printed the response body as shown below. Hope it helps someone out there :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may do this using a scheduling tool that can launch command lines and use Newman ...
I don't think Postman can do it on its own

Alexandre

EDIT:
You may do this using a scheduling tool that can launch command lines and use Newman ... I don't think Postman can do it on its own

check this postman feature : https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/monitors/intro_monitors

Comment: I can't use command line in my project. Probably there is no way.

Comment: no TFS or jenkins, or any continuous integration tool ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if there is no other possibility, you can actually try doing this:
- launch postman runner
- configure the highest possible number of iterations
- configure the delay (in milliseconds) to fit your scheduling requirement

It is absolutely awful, but if the delay variable can be set high enough, it might work. 
It implies that postman is continuousely running.

Comment: Slight detail : the delay is applied BEFORE the first iteration is launched ... it is definitely not a good solution  :(

Answer (score 0):

from postman v10.2.1 onwards you can schedule your collections to run directly (without using monitors) on the specified times

check out here - https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/scheduling-collection-runs/